# Criar um programa que seja utilizável no Windows

Tags: java, windows

Sou estudante de programação, ainda no primeiro ano do meu curso. Até agora estudei `Java`, `C`, `Haskell` e `Script Shell`. Sou bastante funcional em `Java` e `C`.

Eu sei escrever código, compilar e excecutar num terminal do `Linux`, mas imaginemos que eu quero criar uma aplicação que rode no `Windows`. Eu escrevo o meu código - em `Java`, por exemplo - criando uma simples calculadora.

**Depois de ter o código, como faço para criar uma aplicação que possa ser rodada no Windows, um chamado "programa"?**

Se for um processo muito complexo para o meu grau de competências, digam logo isso, por favor.

Desde já obrigado a quem me tentar ajudar :)

Comment: É só dar dois cliques no .jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tendo como base um exemplo bastante simples: criar uma calculadora. Depois de ter o código, como faço para criar uma aplicação que possa ser rodada no Windows, um chamado "programa"?

Supondo que você esteja no Windows e que as as classes da sua calculadora estejam localizadas em uma pasta `src`, sendo a classe `com.example.Calculadora` a classe principal, você pode fazer isso para compilar o seu programa em um arquivo `calculadora.jar` (supondo que a sua JDK esteja corretamente instalada):

```
cd src
dir /s /B *.java > ../sources.txt
cd ..
javac -encoding utf8 -d bin @sources.txt
jar -cfe calculadora.jar com.example.Calculadora -C bin .
```

Se você quiser compilar no unix/linux, mesmo que depois vá (ou não) usar o JAR produzido no windows, pode fazer assim (mudando apenas a segunda linha):

```
cd src
find -name "*.java" > ../sources.txt
cd ..
javac -encoding utf8 -d bin @sources.txt
jar -cfe calculadora.jar com.example.Calculadora -C bin .
```

Para executá-lo em um ambiente (unix/linux ou windows) **onde haja uma JVM compatível corretamente instalada**, você pode clicar duas vezes no arquivo `calculadora.jar` ou então fazer isso:

```
java -jar calculadora.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

Programas criados na linguagem Java rodam na maquina Virtual Java, logo não são stand-alone, eles dependem de que o usuário tenha JavaVM instalado, é impossível rodar um programa escrito em Java sem isto.

Compilar um programa em C, C++, etc, vai ser compilado baseado no compilador usado, não tem como rodar em Windows algo que foi compilado para Linux, assim como não tem como rodar algo que foi compilado para **Mac OS X v10.1** rodar no **Mac OS X v10.13**, isto devido a arquitetura usada por ambos sistemas operacionais.

Compilar em Windows geralmente tem compatibilidade entre os sistemas da familia Windows, mas depende muito do compilador que usoue das APIs usada para escrever o código.

Então para resumir, se é Java vai rodar em diversos sistemas desde que tenha JavaVM instalado, se for C vai ter que compilar em arquitetura por arquitetura que desejar executar o programa.

Linux geralmente não tem compatibilidade entre diferentes distros Linux, por este motivo algumas aplicações geralmente são distribuídas em sources e você tem que compilar com GCC (ou outro compilador que a distro e/ou repositórios disponham), claro que não há garantias de funcionamento, vai depender de quem escreveu o código.

Comment: Na verdade, já vi alguns programas em Java que são stand-alone ao usar o seguinte truque: Eles têm uma JVM inteira exclusiva embutida dentro deles. Essa abordagem é bastante incomum e eu só recomendaria para casos muito específicos, mas existe sim.

Comment: @VictorStafusa todos programas que prometem tornar seu programa Node.js, Python e Java fazem o uso disto. A questão é que o JavaVM tem que ser compativel com a arquitetura, então isso não pode ser considerado, pois uma javavm para windows não vai funcionar em linux e provavelmente o gerador de executável copia o JavaVM da maquina aonde foi gerada, a não ser que exista um programa muito bom que crie um stand-alone com as javavms para os sistemas mais populares, o que provavelmente vai fazer um programa simples pesar horrores.